# The same pipeline or shader is used while drawing multiple Objects in Vulkan

Tags: c++, shader, drawing, pipeline, vulkan

I created a for-loop, that creates descriptorSets(and descriptorLayouts etc.) and pipelines(which are indentical besides the shader) for each Object. I store the pipelines in vectors and descriporSets in nested vectors.

When i want to draw these objects it first binds the vertices and indices with one buffer which is the same buffer for all objects(it just uses an offset) it then iterates through the number of objects i have specified ("MODEL_ARRAY_SIZE") and for each object it gets the corresponding vector index:

```
VkBuffer vertexBuffers[] = { vertexBuffer };
VkDeviceSize offsets[] = { 0 };
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffer, 0, 1, vertexBuffers, offsets);

vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffer, indexBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < MODEL_ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
    vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout[i], 0, 1, &descriptorSets[i][currentFrame], 0, nullptr);

    vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, graphicsPipeline[i]);

    vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffer, static_cast<uint32_t>(indices.size()), 1, indicesOffsets[i], verticesOffsets[i], 0);
}
```

The problem is that the objects i draw use the same shader or pipeline (they have the same texture and so on..), which is wierd because it uses different shaders for each pipeline.

Comment: Each object should almost certainly not have its own pipeline.

Comment: But in almost every tutorial/documentation about multiple objects they create pipelines for each objects like in this one: https://mr-vasifabdullayev.medium.com/multiple-object-rendering-in-vulkan-3d07aa583cec | And how should i then use different shader for each Object?

Comment: I don´t try to copy Tutorials but i still need to look up some things (like multiple object rendering) so i know where i need to start, because i am new to Vulkan and how should i program something when i have literally no idea how to do it.

Comment: And how should i now draw multiple objects with different shaders?

Comment: No one is saying you can’t use multiple shaders, it’s just that each object should likely not have its own shader. Pipeline changes are incredibly slow, which is why some of that performance was offloaded to precompiling the pipeline. Generally you should only have a couple of shaders, e.g. a static opaque, animated opaque, static translucent, animated translucent, and probably something special for terrain. Everything else should probably be changed via textures, uniforms, and push constants.